Spammers are trying to take advantage of this site. Shouldn't actions be taken, before things get out of control?
I've noticed spammers with blatant usernames like ChineseHulu.com and Chinese.Tutor.Frank, who have extensive advertisement in their profiles, and are spamming random questions just in order to advertise themselves. They seem to have found the wrong place for spamming. Shouldn't administrators delete those promotional questions ASAP and block/delete those users? If no action is taken, then other spammers might think this site is an easy target and swarm in, therefore quickly deteriorating its quality and putting the community at risk.

Sadly you can't report a user's profile(and as I understand it's OK to leave contacts/self promotion in user's profile), the only thing you could do is probably flag their posts, But what do you put for the reason"asking questions that they actually know", or are they "gaming the platform"? I am not sure. But I believe people will flag their post(I personally will) if they went too far.

The questions and answers from those two accounts look decent enough. However, it is a violation of site terms to use them for cross-voting. The moderators can choose to merge duplicate accounts or tolerate them. However, if you believe the user is trying to game the system, do flag those posts up so that moderators can take a closer look. I believe they have the proper tools to look out for these. Meanwhile, if the questions and answers are of low quality, you can down-vote once you earn enough reputation.

Unless they are consistently promoting their own sites/services via questions and/or answers, then I don't see a problem with it.

Are user names that represent domains allowed?
Policy on display names
The consensus is that unless the username is blatantly offensive, there's nothing wrong with self-promotion via username (or their profile as an extension). Plus if they are contributing useful content, there is no downside.
